# Difference between "Somnoler" and "Sommeiller"

Tags: sens, littérature

Is there a difference in meaning between **somnoler** and **sommeiller** and when should I use one and when other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a lot of descriptions from the [Trésor de la langue française informatisé](http://atilf.atilf.fr/). Somnoler and sommeiller can be used as synonyms in some contexts, especially talking about inanimate beings (a town). There are however a few subtle differences. Substantives **sommeil** and **somnolence** indeed have different meanings.

I will restrict to human beings, and try to highlight when the meanings differ.

Old meanings for sommeiller include sleep, and death. It now denotes a shallow sleep, possibly short, either close to awakening or falling asleep. Or an inactive, passive state.

Somnoler, to what I understand and use, is closer to half-sleep, meaning partly awake, partly sleepy. You may use somnoler when you are doing something, and gently falling asleep (chosen examples for TLF: "être temporairement inutilisé", "s'engourdir", "s'endormir en faisant quelque chose".).

For instance, I would say:

- le conducteur somnolait au volant (en roulant),

but:

- le conducteur sommeillait au volant de sa voiture (à l'arrêt).

One talks about "somnolence au volant". While not a proof, the expression "sommeille au volant" seems much less frequent with a common search engine than "somnole au volant".

To make it short, sommeiller often denotes a steady state, somewhere between the state of sleep and wake. While somnoler is more evolutive (slowly oscillating between wake and sleep), or denotes a   temporary state or situation. Sommeiller can be short or shallow, but somnoler is more intermittent.

Comment: As said in gustav's answer, I would not use "sommeiller" this way... I would only use "somnoler" to mean "a steady state, somehow halfway between sleep and wake"... By the way, your links are broken...

Comment: @Random I have added an example, and subtle differences. Could you tall me more about "I would not use "sommeiller" this way"?

Comment: the only 2 ways I would use "sommeiller" are in "réveille le lion qui sommeille en toi", and "j'ai sommeil"... I would never use "sommeiller" in a direct form (as in your 2nd example "le conducteur sommeillait au volant de sa voiture (à l'arrêt)."), it sounds very strange to me...

Comment: From Le petit Robert: "Dans le break, en revenant, tous les hommes, hormis Jean, sommeillaient" (Maupassant). I agree this may sound a bit old-fashioned. The example for somnoler is "Des vertus somnolent, faute de pouvoir se manifester" (Daudet), where the meaning is about the same as sommeiller.

Answer (score -1):

In France, no one use "sommeiller", you have to use "somnoler" when you are about to sleep.

Comment: Welcome to FrenchLanguage. Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I think that "Sommeiller" take two "m" and [is actually used more often than "somnoler"](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=sommeiller,somnoler) by french speaker.

Comment: Ok, I asked an older french friend who said to me that "Sommeiller" does exist but it's not really use. "Sommeiller" means you are sleeping, or trying to, it's a bit fancy. PS: I'm french from Paris and I never heard about "Sommeiller" before. ,,

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas In France, I would never use "sommeiller" with this meaning. The only way I would use it is as in "réveille le lion qui sommeille en toi", which is very different...

Comment: Ok, no problem for expressions